# After GIT merge I still have the old branches

Tags: git, github, merge, github-desktop

I am sorry if this seems simple to some but I'm still getting my head around GIT.  I thought all was fine.  I'd create a branch, make edits, then merge back into master.

Then the other day I checked and there are still two old branches there.  I tried to merge them again, but after merge I still see them.  I've spent some time trying to figure this out but can't.  Here they are, still active:

[image]

In the Merge tool it says "no commits differ" for both of these branches.
[image]

Can anyone offer any ideas as to why they are still there and how to properly merge them (or not have them show up anymore)?  I'm worried I may lose work if I continue before resolving this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you merge a branch the branch doesn't get deleted. You have to do that manually:

`git branch -d my_branch_name`

If the branch hasn't been merged it will prompt you to use `-D` instead of `-d`.

Comment: Thank you /u/Zarwan. Much appreciated. I guess a question is Should i delete them or leave them for "just in case"? Is there a general rule of thumb i should be following?

Comment: Typically you delete them after they have been merged. GitHub actually prompts you to if you merge through a pull request. It is safe, as you can always revert commits. @robster

Answer (score 2):

A branch is just a *pointer* to a certain commit. You can have as many as you want, and merging them certainly doesn't delete them, just like merging a commit does not delete a commit. That is in fact the development strategy chosen by a number of projects, or close enough ([1](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/),[2](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/gitlab_flow.html#release-branches-with-gitlab-flow),[3](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows)). In these documents, multiple branches run in parallel, and are regularly merged together.

Once you are done working on your branch, and have successfully merged it, you can delete it with

```
git branch -d branch_name
```

As @Zarwan pointed out. using `-D` directly here is dangerous, as you will not be prompted to confirm if the branch is not successfully merged. So, prefer using `-d`, except in some rare occasion.

If you are talking about a distant branch, the right way (there is many other documentation pages dedicated to this topic) to delete it is to perform:

```
git push remote_name :branch_name
```

essentially pushing an empty object to `branch_name` of `remote_name` (which is probably `origin` if you cloned form it).

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation /u/MayeuIC.  It's very much appreciated.  I've deleted them as the master is as I want it and from now on I'll be sure to delete correctly to keep it tidy.  Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git branch -d *branchname*`

Answer (score -1):

Exactly, Git merge means: merge your branch into annother branch.

git merge your_branch master

This commande don't delete your branch. So to delete your branch ; you use :

git branch -D your_branch

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Comment: `-D` overrides a sanity check that shouldn't be overridden here. Use `-d` as in Zarwan's answer.